# What is **/*.fileExtension used for in ant?

Tags: ant

I can't find a direct definition of how this works? Is it a regex of some type?

for ex.

```
<ftp action="del"
   server="ftp.apache.org"
   userid="anonymous"
   password="me@myorg.com">
<fileset>
  <include name="**/*.tmp"/>
</fileset>
```

what is the include name = double asterisks used for?

How is it different from this

```
 <ftp action="list"
   server="ftp.apache.org"
   userid="anonymous"
   password="me@myorg.com"
   listing="data/ftp.listing">
<fileset>
  <include name="**"/>
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are what Ant calls 'patterns' and are similar to file patterns in Unix with the addition of the '**' pattern.

A single `*` matches zero or more characters, `?` matches one character.

When `**` is used as the name of a directory in the pattern, it matches zero or more directories. For example: `/test/**` matches all files/directories under `/test/`

So

```
<include name="**/*.tmp"/>
```

matches any file ending in `.tmp` in any directory

```
<include name="**"/>
```

matches anything.

A longer description is [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html)